# Rules of initializing companion object values in Scala

Tags: scala, initialization, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

My game has a Sounds object like this:

```
object Sounds {
  SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/")

  val EXPLOSION_0 = ESound("explosion1.ogg")
  val EXPLOSION_1 = ESound("explosion2.ogg")
  val EXPLOSION_2 = ESound("explosion3.ogg")
  val IMPACT_0 = ESound("impact1.ogg", 0.4f)
  val IMPACT_1 = ESound("impact2.ogg", 0.4f)
  val IMPACT_2 = ESound("impact3.ogg", 0.4f)
  val BONUS = ESound("bonus.ogg", 0.7f)

  // -- snip --

  def load() {
    println("Sounds loaded")
  }

  case class ESound(sound_file: String, volume: Float = 1) {
    private val sound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(AndEngine.engine.getSoundManager, AndEngine.activity.get, sound_file)
    sound.setVolume(volume)
    sound.setLoopCount(0)

    def play() { sound.play() }
  }
}
```

I've removed many methods etc for brevity. But the basic idea was that Scala initalizes the object lazily, so first time I call some method (`load()`) on this object it will get initialized. This would be done for example after texture loading etc.

But with the above code, the first time I press some menu button in my game, I get a long pause as it only then will load all those sounds (caused by the `SoundFactory.createSound...` in the constructor).

Now if I change the `load` method to following:

```
    println("Sounds loaded, " + BONUS.toString)
```

All sounds get loaded properly.

So, why does this happen? How and why does Scala initialize the Sounds object so I can call the load() but doesn't load it's own values in the constructor part? What are the rules for companion object initialization?

Comment: CLICK is one of ESound vals declared? There isn't any CLICK in provided code.

Answer (score 6):

According to section 5.4 of the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> *Note that the value defined by an object definition is instantiated lazily. The
>   new m$cls constructor is evaluated not at the point of the object definition, but is
>   instead evaluated the first time m is dereferenced during execution of the program
>   (which might be never at all). An attempt to dereference m again in the course
>   of evaluation of the constructor leads to a infinite loop or run-time error. Other
>   threads trying to dereferencem while the constructor is being evaluated block until
>   evaluation is complete.*

The companion object should be constructed the first time it is referenced - which I think is your understanding too. This works on a the following example:

```
object Sounds {
  val EXPLOSION_0 = ESound("EXPLOSION_0")
  def load() { println("loaded") }
  case class ESound(file: String) {
    private val sound = {
      println("waiting 1s before loading " + file)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      "sound from " + file
    }
  }
}

object C extends App {
  Sounds.load()
}
```

Prints:

```
[info] Running C
waiting 1s before loading EXPLOSION_0
loaded
```

So your unexpected behavior probably comes from the sections you haven't posted.